# How do I get the model validation decorations output to my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following data model in my MVC app

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

On the view I'm using AngularJS, and I'd rather have it do as much validation up front instead of making a round trip to the server for something simple like checking the length of a string.

Right now I have to hardcode `<input ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="100" />` - but is there a way to get these numbers out of the decorations of the model?  Here's some pseudo-code for what I'm hoping can be done:

```
<input
    ng-minlength="@Html.ValidationFor(m => m.Password).MinimumLength"
    ng-maxlength="@Html.ValidationFor(m => m.Password).MaximumLength" />
```

Similarly, if a model is decorated with `[EmailAddress]` would it be possible to get the regular expression that is uses to be output into my view?

---

## Edit!

Major thanks to @ChrisPratt below for pointing me in the right direction!  I used his base code there to make the helper that I needed.  This isn't perfect, but it's my first shot at it and it works.

Now I can use the following

```
@Html.ValidationAttributesFor(m => m.Password, ValidationHelper.ValidationAttributresEnum.MinimumLength)
```

And that will call this class

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class ValidationHelper
    {
        public enum ValidationAttributresEnum
        {
            MinimumLength,
            MaximumLength
        }

        public static string ValidationAttributesFor<TParameter, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TParameter> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TParameter, TValue>> expression, ValidationAttributresEnum val)
        {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            var validators = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.GetValidators(metadata, htmlHelper.ViewContext);
            var rules = validators.SelectMany(v => v.GetClientValidationRules()).ToList();

            if (rules.Any(x => x is ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule))
            {
                var p = rules.FirstOrDefault(x => x is ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule).ValidationParameters;
                if(val.Equals(ValidationAttributresEnum.MinimumLength)){
                    return p["min"].ToString();
                }
                
                if (val.Equals(ValidationAttributresEnum.MaximumLength))
                {
                    return p["max"].ToString();
                }
            }

            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct way like you hope. If you use [editor templates](http://cpratt.co/displaytemplates-and-editortemplates-for-fun-and-profit/) then you can get information about the property inside the template via `ViewData.ModelMetadata`. That nets you easily a few things. You can use `ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired` to determine if the `[Required]` attribute was set. Similarly you can get things like the format string via `ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString`. For things like your data types (`DataType.EmailAddress`, etc.) you can get it from `ViewData.ModelMetadata.DataTypeName`. However, that only tells you the type that was set, not whatever regex or whatever will be used to validate it.

For the more complex validation rules, you'll need something like the following:

```
@{
    var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach(var validator in ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetValidators(ViewContext).SelectMany(v => v.GetClientValidationRules())) {
        var parameters = validator.ValidationParameters;

        if(validator is ModelClientValidationRegexRule) {
            htmlAttributes.Add("ng-pattern", parameters["pattern"]);
        } else if(validator is ModelClientValidationRangeRule) {
            htmlAttributes.Add("ng-minlength", parameters["min"]);
            htmlAttributes.Add("ng-maxlength", parameters["max"]);
        } else if(validator is ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule) {
            htmlAttributes.Add("ng-minlength", parameters["minlength"]);
            htmlAttributes.Add("ng-maxlength", parameters["maxlength"]);
        }
    }
}

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, htmlAttributes)
```

You can, and probably should, factor that code out into an extension method on something like `HtmlHelper`, so you can just call the extension method and get back a dictionary of your attributes. For an example, see https://gist.github.com/andybooth/1029068. That's also where I adapted the code above from.

Comment: Thanks!  Check my edit above to see what I came up with!  Any suggestions for improving that would be appreciated!